# Algebra Simplification if possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation: $A(\frac{w}{A\alpha})^\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} = (p + w)\gamma$.

I would like to rewrite this equation in the form w = ...

Is this possible? When I tried graphing the two expressions, I get a solution on the graph because there exists a point where the two expressions intersect. I know this is only algebera but I am having a hard time rewriting this equation. Any insights will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are $A, \alpha, \omega, \gamma ... $

Comment: Wouldn't it be interesting if this was a homework assignment in a Complex Analysis class and the professor doesn't tell you what the values of the constants are and he ask derive an expression for w?